C.E.P. PEÑA GRANDE
Que yo sepa, C.E.P. en "C.E.P. PEÑA GRANDE" significa "centro de especialidades". Mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué "centro de especialidades" no se abrevia "C. (Centro) D. (De) P. (,Especialidades)" en este caso? !Muchas gracias!

¡Hola!
Para empezar, que conste que en mi mente C.E.P. significaba Centro de Educación Primaria.
Respecto a tu pregunta, investigando un poco he encontrado lo siguiente sobre el CEP Peña Grande donde hace referencia a Centro de Especialidades Periférico Peña Grande, lo que daría sentido a la abreviatura utilizada. Comparando la información con la aportada en tu enlace parece que hacen referencia al mismo centro, no obstante la denominación es distinta.

Para completar la respuesta de R18:

Los acrónimos suelen omitir para su formación los artículos, las preposiciones y las conjunciones que aparecen en la denominación
completa, salvo si son necesarios para facilitar su pronunciación:
ACUDE (por Asociación de Consumidores y Usuarios de España), pyme (por
pequeña y mediana empresa).

Fundeu
Esa es la razón de que no sea CDEP: Es más difícil de pronunciar.
